# Need to Pass data when user tabs on Table View row to another DetailedInterfaceController in Watchkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

Hello I am new to IOS Watchkit Development.

I need to pass the data when user tabs on the table row. I have tried both ways using `segue` and using the `pushControllerWithName` and even tried `presentControllerWithName` in the method

```
-(void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
     [self contextForSegueWithIdentifier:@"navigare" inTable:self.tbl rowIndex:rowIndex];
     //And Tried following
     [self pushControllerWithName:(NSString *)@"ProfileInterfaceController" context: rowValue];

}
```

Any help here ?

Comment: What result does this code give you? How are you setting the value of rowValue? Are you using a segue in IB or not?

Comment: is contextForSegueWithIdentifier:@"navigare" a typo? Check your identifiers match in Interface Builder with your code.

Comment: @rdelmar this is the inbuilt method like `UITABLEVIEWDELEGATE` methods. It tells which row is selected, i need this only the thing is i am not able to pass the data to `ProfileInterfaceController`

Comment: @phillfarrugia No buddy i have the same name `navigare` to segue identifier. This is not typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you having issues accessing the 'rowValue' from ProfileInterfaceController? Or are you just unsure how to accomplish this?

WatchKit allows you to send data to a WKInterfaceController with a segue using the ***presentControllerWithName:Context:*** method.

**Name** - is the name assigned to the destination WKInterfaceController in Interface Builder (not the name of the file or any other).

**Context** - is an NSDictionary parameter which you use to send data.

When the destination WKInterfaceController is initialised the ***awakeWithContext:*** method is called, and your context dictionary is available for use.

In the code snippet you've provided it's hard to understand 'rowValue'. This needs to be wrapped up in an NSDictionary object before sending.

Check out [Apple's Framework Reference for more information](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW27)

Unrelated, but worth noting - it's unnecessary to prepend (NSString *) when using the NSString literal syntax (@"This is a string") in Objective C.

Comment: I have used following code `-(void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{   NSDictionary *d=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hi" forKey:@"nm"];
    [self presentControllerWithName:@"ProfileInterfaceController" context:d];
}` nothing happens. It is not getting redicted to ProfileInterface controller

Comment: I forgot to add ProfileInterfaceController as identifier. Solved now Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "updatepurposesegue"){
        var vrc = segue.destinationViewController as NewPurposeViewController;

        vrc.temp = row

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks incomplete, some explanation could help understand the code

Comment: the code what you wrote is in swift while the question asked refers to objective c